# [Boost]::DI creating unique shared_ptr objects from injector

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection, shared-ptr

Taking this sample code I'd like to have as a result that
button1 and button2 are two separate ojects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "di.hpp"
namespace di = boost::di;

struct CommandQueue {
    void addCommand() {}
};

struct Control {
    Control( CommandQueue &cq ) : cq( cq ) {
        static int sid{};
        id = ++sid;
    }

    CommandQueue& cq;
    int id{};
};

int main() {

    auto injector = di::make_injector( di::bind<CommandQueue>().in(di::singleton) );

    auto button1 = injector.create<std::shared_ptr<Control>>();
    auto button2 = injector.create<std::shared_ptr<Control>>();

    std::cout << "button1->id = " << button1->id << std::endl;
    std::cout << "button2->id = " << button2->id << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The current output is:

> button1->id = **1**
>
> button2->id = **1**

Instead of the intended:

> button1->id = **1**
>
> button2->id = **2**

Removing the `di::singleton` lifetime scope from `CommandQueue` singleton also doesn't fix it. 
I know the lifetime scope for a shared_ptr is a singleton by default but I thought that was referred to the injected dependency not the actual object created with create.

Comment: What is the relevance of `addCommand`

Comment: It's just a placeholder to justify the use of CommandQueue as singleton but even without that the code would still create 1 object instead of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the simplest thing could be

```
auto button1 = injector.create<Control>();
auto button2 = injector.create<Control>();

std::cout << "button1.id = " << button1.id() << std::endl;
std::cout << "button2.id = " << button2.id() << std::endl;
```

Prints

```
button1.id = 1
button2.id = 2
```

---

If you **must** have shared-pointers, the next simplest thing would be

```
auto button1 = std::make_shared<Control>(injector.create<Control>());
auto button2 = std::make_shared<Control>(injector.create<Control>());

std::cout << "button1->id = " << button1->id() << std::endl;
std::cout << "button2->id = " << button2->id() << std::endl;
```

---

**Conceptually** you want a control-factory, not a control. So, you should consider creating a factory from the dependency container:

```
#include <boost/di.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
namespace di = boost::di;

struct CommandQueue {
    void addCommand() {}
};

struct Control {
    Control(CommandQueue &cq) : _cq(cq), _id(idgen()) { }

    int id() const { return _id; }

    struct Factory {
        Factory(CommandQueue& cq) : _cq(cq) {}
        CommandQueue& _cq;

        template <typename... Args>
        auto operator()(Args&&... args) const {
            return std::make_shared<Control>(_cq, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
  private:
    static int idgen() { static int sid{}; return ++sid; }
    CommandQueue &_cq;
    int _id{};
};

int main() {
    auto injector = di::make_injector(di::bind<CommandQueue>().in(di::singleton));

    auto factory = injector.create<Control::Factory>();
    auto button1 = factory();
    auto button2 = factory();

    std::cout << "button1->id = " << button1->id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "button2->id = " << button2->id() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to break the OCP in our lib so converting the shared_ptr to an object wasn't a good option, I have considered the "naked" make_shared like you have suggested in your second example but I wasn't sure it was best practice with DI, lastly yes I've already encapsulated the real code into a factory but still i was wondering if with DI I would get away from calling make_shared on the left hand side of the create, which I didn't want to do to avoid deep copy and having to write a copy ctor. Basically I just wanted re-assurance that I wasn't doing anything terribly wrong :)

Comment: Hmm no why would you think that? I wanted to elaborate my thought process and I wasn't sure as if to edit the original question with extra info or reply as a comment

Comment: Well. I'm not sure what to add to my answer. The usual approach is to vote up if helpful, down if unhelpful. Reiterating the premise in a comment is not very productive. Reassurance granted

Comment: Very much appreciated the time spent on elaborating your answer, upvoted and I'm just waiting to see if there are going to be other answers before I tick it green.

Comment: I hope so too! I don't have a lot of experience with Boost DI (though I played with it before). I'm not sure many people use it. Kudos for bringing it back to my attention :)